# Add New Shipping Carrier

Tags: magento-1.9.3.4, carrier

I want to Add New Shipping Carrier in the Shipping ->Shipping and Tracking Information->Drop-down. so how I can I add extra shipping carriers.

Answer (score 0):

You can add addition carrier option in below file

```
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Shipment/Create/Tracking.php
```

Go to Line 70 , Add below line before `return $carriers;` in getCarriers() Function

```
$carriers['My Custom Carrier'] = Mage::helper('sales')->__('My Custom Carrier');
```

Replace `My Custom Carrier` with your carrier name.

Comment: from above code I can not track orders.

Comment: editing the magneto core is never good idea, instead create a new module